# Jquery: Enable submit only when specific fields are complete

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to enable submit button only when some specific fields are complete otherwise keep disabled.

Given some IDs(of input type- text,checkbox,radio) ,iterate and check if value present,then enable or disable submit accordingly.

```
sample snippet:
----------------
<input type="text" id="first">
<input type="checkbox" id="second">
<input type="radio" id="third">
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit" disabled/>
```

I tried below, but didn't help.

http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/641/

http://jsfiddle.net/M4vqZ/8/

Appreciate your help specific to the use-case mentioned above.

Comment: Please make it a habit of posting your code. The jsfiddle may differ  from your code in many ways possible, hence making it impossible to debug.

Comment: Your code in http://jsfiddle.net/qKG5F/641/ seems to be working fine! What's the problem?

Comment: May be you wanted to check only some specific fields are completes or not then have a look this jsFiddle, sorry i was little confused in JSFiddle post request so wrote everything in HTML area -> https://jsfiddle.net/1s9zpm27/7/

Comment: To elaborate more, given the form contains -

Comment: To elaborate more, given the form contains -
<input type="text" id="first">
<input type="checkbox" id="second">
<input type="radio" id="third">
<input type="checkbox" id="fourth">
<input type="submit" id="submitBtn" value="Submit" disabled/> .
I want to enable Submit button only when the input Ids-first,second,third has value(dont want to check for Id-fourth), otherwise keep the submit button disabled.